# How to remove extra array from JSON php

Tags: php, mysql, json

I want to remove extra array from my json. So need a help.

**This is how my current json appear:**

[image: The current json]

**The below image shows, what i need (Without array):**

[image: The JSON I want]

**This is my php code**

```
<?php 

define('HOST','localhost');
define('USER','appzcvfy_admin');
define('PASS','adminroot1');
define('DB','appzcvfy_sinala_short_stories');


$conn = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);

$sql1 = "select * from table_3";

$result1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);

$MainArray = array();
$Facilities = array();
$OpeningHours = array();

while ($row1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)) {

    $Facilities['t1_id'] = $row1['id'];
    $Facilities['t1_name'] = $row1['name'];
    $Facilities['t1_link'] = $row1['link'];

    $Facilities['OpeningHours'] = array();

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM table_4 WHERE (id) = ".$row1['id']."";
    $result2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);

    while ($row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2)) {

        $OpeningHours['t2_id'] = $row2['id'];
        $OpeningHours['t2_name'] = $row2['name'];
        $OpeningHours['t2_link'] = $row2['link'];
        $OpeningHours['t2_url'] = $row2['url'];

        array_push($Facilities['OpeningHours'],$OpeningHours);
    }    

    array_push($MainArray,$Facilities);
}

$jsonData = json_encode(array('server_respnose' => $MainArray), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);

echo $jsonData;

?>
```

Can anyone rearrange my php code as my wanting. Thank you

Comment: why not join the two tables rather than have nested queries like this?

Comment: Please PASTE that JSON, we hate screenshots, we cant do anything with a screenshot

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you only have one row you don't need a loop, rather than creating a temporary array and then adding it, just set the values directly into the element...

```
$row2=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result2);
$Facilities['OpeningHours']['t2_id'] = $row2['id'];
$Facilities['OpeningHours']['t2_name'] = $row2['name'];
$Facilities['OpeningHours']['t2_link'] = $row2['link'];
$Facilities['OpeningHours']['t2_url'] = $row2['url'];
```

As suggested by RamRaider, you could reduce this to 1 query

```
select t3.id as t1_id, t3.name as t1_name, 
        t3.link as t1_link, t3.url as t1_url, 
        t4.id as t2_id, t4.name as t2_name, 
        t4.link as t2_link, t4.url as t2_url
    from table_3 t3
    join table_4 t4 on t4.id = t3.id
```

and just fetch the details to output from this instead - read his answer for a fuller explanation of this.

Answer (score 1):

I've just seen before posting that I may have been pipped to the post with the table joins but here goes anyway ~ it might help simplify matters.

```
<?php

    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USER','appzcvfy_admin');
    define('PASS','adminroot1');
    define('DB','appzcvfy_sinala_short_stories');


    $conn = mysqli_connect( HOST, USER, PASS, DB );
    $data=array();

    $sql='select 
            t3.`id` as `id1`, 
            t3.`name` as `name1`, 
            t3.`link` as `link11, 
            t4.`id` as `id2`, 
            t4.`name` as `name2`,
            t4.`link` as `link2`,
            t4.`url` 
        from table_3 t3 
        join table_4 t4 on t3.id=t4.id';

    $res=$conn->query( $sql );
    if( $res ){
        while( $rs=$res->fetch_object() ){
            $data[]=array(
                't1_id'     =>  $rs->id1,
                't1_name'   =>  $rs->name1,
                't1_link'   =>  $rs->link1,
                'OpeningHours'  =>  array(
                    't2_id'     =>  $rs->id2,
                    't2_name'   =>  $rs->name2,
                    't2_link'   =>  $rs->link2,
                    't2_url'    =>  $rs->url,
                )
            );      
        }
        $payload=array('server response'=>$data);
        $json=json_encode( $payload );
        echo $json;
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declare it as an `array()`, so delete that bit:

```
$Facilities['OpeningHours'] = array(); // delete this
```

And replace this:

```
array_push($Facilities['OpeningHours'],$OpeningHours);
```

with this:

```
$Facilities['OpeningHours'] = $OpeningHours;
```